# QProcess gpg2 error in windows

Tags: gnupg, qt5.5

I need to encrypt some text with gpg using Qt. QCA is no choice.
My function is working in Linux but in Windows I get exitCode 2.

Executing the gpg2.exe with the same arguments on the commandline is working like expected.

```
QString PGPProcess::encrypt(QString toAddress, QString message)
{

    this->start(QStringList() << "--trust-model always" << "-a" << "-e" << "-r " + toAddress);
    this->waitForStarted(PROCESS_WAIT);
    this->write(message.toUtf8());
    this->waitForBytesWritten(PROCESS_WAIT);
    this->closeWriteChannel();
    this->waitForFinished(PROCESS_WAIT);

    if(this->exitCode()) {
        qDebug() << this->exitCode();
        return message;
    } else {
        return this->readAllStandardOutput();
    }

}
```

I think it hast to do with closeWriteChannel(). Commandline has to send CRTL-D (Linux) that gpg is encrypting the written text.

In Windows CTRL-D does not do anything, there I have to press CTRL-C.
But calling terminate() on the QProcess does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok simply changing the arguments QStringList to the following does the trick ...

```
this->start(QStringList() << "--trust-model" << "always" << "-a" << "-e" << "-r" << toAddress);
```